# jQuery Sliding Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a sliding div on my page which is using jQuery, I'd like to have multiple instances.

At the moment he jQuery script is...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();

$('.show_hide').click(function(){
$(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
});

});
```

and my link/div is...

```
<a href="#" class="show_hide" style="display: inline; ">test<span style="float:right;">+</span></a>

<div class="slidingDiv" style="display: none; ">
<div class="information-alert">test</div>
```

How would I go about creating multiple instances? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go by changing

```
$(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
```

to

```
$(this).next().slideToggle();
```

meaning "slideToggle the element that goes right after the clicked element".

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kZ3jj/)

Answer (score 1):

Trying to get my script to work such that when the contact div is down and you click any-where but the contact div it will slide back up. I know i am going about this wrong i was hoping on some tips if possible thanks.

**[Here is a link](http://travismichael.net/new_tmdesigns/index.php#)** to what i am doing.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("a.contact-btn").toggle(
               function () {
                $("#contact").animate( {"top": "0"}, 900, "linear" );
                },
               function () {
                $("#contact").animate( {"top": "-450px"}, 900, "linear" );
                    });




    $('body').bind('click', function(e) {

        var position = $('#contact').css('marginTop');

        if (position != '-450px') {
            $("#contact").animate( {"top": "-450px"}, 900, "linear" );
            e.preventDefault();
            }

            else if('#contact') {
                 $("#contact").animate( {"top": "0"}, 900, "linear" );
                    }
           });      
             });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the JQuery each method http://api.jquery.com/each/

I am not exactly sure what you want to create multiple instances of: `slidingDiv`?, the show_hide link? both?

Anyway, I am sure that you will need to use the each method to iterate over your multiple instances.